# How to add an external library to java lsp

Tags: lsp, java

I am working on a simple java program, it uses a jason.jar and junit.*.jar (for testing). I usually run the tests through the command line; i never run my programs through and Editor/IDE, I always use the system environment. And while I am able to compile, test, and run the program, I keep getting errors with the lsp saying that modules related to my external .jar's are not found. I think this is because the lsp I am using eclipse.jdt.ls which cannot find the .jars inside my CLASSPATH variable and therefore throws errors. Is there a way to make the lsp errors/warnings go Away? i.e make emacs use the same CLASSPATH as my system

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research and fighting some typos, I resorted to using the build.gradle script.

```
repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs("/path/to/dependencies/")
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation files('dependencies/dependencyOne.jar')
    implementation files('dependencies/dependencyTwo.jar')
    implementation files('dependencies/dependencyThree.jar')    
}
```

Now, someone can perhaps contribute and explain how to add this globally in some sort of init file in either .emacs.d or init.el